# Order of Drag and Drop file urls

Tags: python-3.x, drag-and-drop, pyqt, qlistwidget

I have a `QListWidget` which allows drag and drop of files. This is a pretty standard form which has been covered extensively. The code I have copied below works.

The issue I am encountering is the order of the file entries into the list widget. To illustrate my issue, say the user (by holding shift, ctrl or some other means) selects four files named `1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt` and `4.txt` ordered as described in the Windows file-explorer. When the user drags these four selected files I would like them appended to the list widget in the same order.

However, what in fact happens is that the first file in the list is determined by whichever file in the selected group happens to be clicked at the start of the drag and drop operation. Say the user were click on `3.txt` when starting the drag: then the list widget will be populated as `3.txt, 4.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt`. I want to preserve the order of the files as they were in the Windows file-manager by ignoring whatever file happened to be clicked as part of the selected group at the beginning of the drag operation. I have searched extensively but have not found a solution to this.

```
class FileList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    enableRun = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)
    defaultFilePath = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(FileList,self).__init__()

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.setToolTip('Drag and drop files that you wish to combine')
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        self.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.remove)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
          event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
          super(FileList, self).dragEnterEvent(event)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            super(FileList, self).dragMoveEvent(event)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
            self.defaultFilePath.emit(str(event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile()))
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                self.addItem(str(url.toLocalFile()))
        else:
            super(FileList, self).dropEvent(event)

        self.checkCount()

    def dragLeaveEvent(self,event):
        for item in self.selectedItems():
            self.takeItem(self.row(item))
        self.checkCount()

    def remove(self,item):
        self.takeItem(self.row(item))
        self.checkCount()

    def checkCount(self):
        if self.count() >= 2:
            self.enableRun.emit(True)
        else:
            self.enableRun.emit(False)

    def clear(self):
        super(FileList,self).clear()
        self.checkCount()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the sorting order for your QListWidget in your dropEvent. This example will sort your files in an ascending alphabetical order like: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt ...

```
    self.sortItems(QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks the the current behaviour is optimal.

The order of selection is preserved during drag and drop, because there is no other way to recover that information. Potentially, this can give the user total control over how the dragged items will be displayed in the list. If they want them in some specific order (including the same order as currently shown in the file-manager), they can simply select them as appropriate.

In contrast, the sort-order used by file-managers is easily reproduced, and so there is little value in trying to preserve it. And it's not even clear that it makes sense to do so. What if the file-manager is updated during, or immediately after, the drag and drop operation? What should be the "correct" order?

Ideally, an application should try to preserve the user's selection order when loading the urls into the list, and then provide a way to sort/unsort it afterwards. Second best would probably be to just sort it alphabetically, since that's what most users would expect to happen anyway.